# Redirect loop while using url_for function with parameters in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I get a redirect loop when I try to use the redirect and url_for functions in flask as follows:

```
@app.route('/edit/<id>' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit (id):
#Getting user by primary key:
post = Post.query.get(id)
if request.method == 'POST':        
    post.title = request.form['title']
    post.text =  request.form['text']
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')     

return redirect(url_for('edit',  id=id, post=post))
```

Update: Solved http://techarena51.com/index.php/flask-sqlalchemy-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I presume you only want to redirect if the user submitted a POST request? I think your code should be:

```
@app.route('/edit/<id>' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit (id):
#Getting user by primary key:
post = Post.query.get(id)
if request.method == 'POST':        
    post.title = request.form['title']
    post.text =  request.form['text']
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')     
    return redirect(url_for('edit',  id=id, post=post))

# The rest of this code is executed when a GET is performed
return render_template("edit.html",id=id, post=post)
```

otherwise, yes, your current code will redirect to the same route every time it is accessed. I've updated my example to show how you need to render the edit template when the request method is not POST.

Comment: can you give me an example, of how to tackle the rest of the code when a get is submitted

Comment: It does not seem to be executing the first return, I get the edit url is not found on the server. I even changed it to show the index page but no luck.

Comment: It is more likely to be failing at render_template. Do you have a template called edit.html?

Comment: yes, I am able to resolve edit/id, the problem is that the return redirect does not seem to be executing once I click on submit and submit a post request. my edit.html code http://pastebin.com/yEKKCWAZ